# Appium: iPhone safari takes more time to execute the same script than Android chrome

Tags: java, ios, iphone, appium-ios, appium-android

I am automating the Mobile web browser on Android and iOS devices.

I am using Page Object model Framework using Java + Appium.

Wrote same script for Chrome and Safari browser.

But Safari takes more time than chrome browser.

For example:

- Login scripts takes **5 minutes** to finish on Android Chrome.
- Login scripts take **40 minutes** to finish on iPhone safari
     browser.

Even it takes 5 to 10 seconds to perform any kind of manipulation while working iOs devices.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, could you please mention the appium, selenium, iOS version's and also could you please share the driver initialization code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the slow execution speed on iPhone safari.

I have faced this issue due to Dependencies.

Previously I was using following dependencies:

- **Installed Appium Version = 1.8.0**
- **Selenium.version = 3.11.0**
- **Appium Java-Client = 5.0.4**

So I have moved following dependencies:

- **Installed Appium Version = 1.8.0**
- **Selenium.version = 3.9.1**
- **Appium Java-Client = 6.0.0-BETA5**

Now test scripts are running very fast on iPhone Safari.

For more information please go through this link [Appium - iPhone Safari](https://discuss.appium.io/t/iphone-safari-takes-more-time-to-execute-the-same-script-than-android-chrome/22923)

Thank you